# having trouble with a simple copy and paste function in google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to call a function from the menu bar to copy a set of values in google sheets to an "archive" tab. The error i'm getting is "Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." here is the code:

```
function archiveCompleted () {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var copyFrom = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("completed autofill");
 var copyDest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Completed Orders");
 var sourceRange = copyFrom.getRange(1,1,copyFrom.getLastRow(),copyFrom.getLastColumn());
 var destRange = copyDest.getRange(copyDest.getLastRow() + 1,1,copyFrom.getLastRow(),copyFrom.getLastColumn()); 
 //1,1,copyFrom.getLastColumn());
 sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destRange);
 spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy From Feildpine'),true);

}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that about your error message of `Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.Range) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.`, unfortunately, I cannot find `setValues` in your showing script. So I'm worried that you miscopied your current script.

But, when I saw your script, I thought that `sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destRange);` is required to be modified. Because the arguments of `copyValuesToRange` are `gridId, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd` or `sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd`. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangegridid,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend), [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyvaluestorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend)

So, in this modification, I would like to propose modifying the line as follows.

#### From:

```
sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destRange);
```

#### To:

```
sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: thank you, thats super helpful! 
played around a bit more and heres how I ended up:
function archiveCompleted () {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var copyFrom = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("completed autofill");
 var copyDest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Completed Orders");
 var sourceRange = copyFrom.getRange(1,1,copyFrom.getLastRow(),copyFrom.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var destRange = copyDest.getRange(copyDest.getLastRow() + 1,1,copyFrom.getLastRow(),copyFrom.getLastColumn()); 
 //sourceRange.copyValuesToRange(destRange);
 destRange.setValues(sourceRange);

}

Comment: @adam Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: no stress at all! Not everyone's english is good, but you still took time out to answer my question -- much appreciated :)
and yes! i did a little of what you mentioned and reworked a few things to make it work. cheers!